# How to use a value imported from a database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Hey Everyone here is my question .
The code below gets data from my database and displays it both in an input field and a button. I want it to be in such a way that if i click the button it should get the value(which is imported from the db).But the problem i am facing is that all the inputs and buttons have the same ids so it  only captures the value of the first button(or so i think). How can i make it in such a way that for every button i click it should have its own separate value.

```
    <?php  
    $dbcon=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");  
    mysqli_select_db($dbcon,"codex"); 
    require('config/server.php');
    ?>
    <table class="table table-striped"> 
    <th>ID</th>  
     <?php  
    $view_users_query="select * from users";//select query for viewing 
     users.  
    $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$view_users_query);//here run the sql 
    query.
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))//while look to fetch the result 
    and store in a array $row.  
    { 
    ?>    

    <!--here showing results in the table -->

    <form id="loginForm" method="" action="" novalidate>
    <tr>
    <div class="panel2"> 
    <main class="content">

    <td><input name="hanis" id="hanis" type="text" value="<?php echo 
    $row['email']?>"  autofocus /></td>

    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" 
    name="hanis" id="hanis" onclick="hanisdata()" value="<?php echo 
    $row['email']?>" ><?php echo $row['email']?></button><</td>

    </main></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    function hanisdata() {
    var hanis=$("hanis").val();

    alert(hanis); 
    // AJAX code to send data to php file.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "hanis.php",
        data: {hanis:hanis},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
         $("#message").html(data);
        $("p").addClass("alert alert-success");
        },
        error: function(err) {
        alert(err);
        }
       });

        }

       </script>
```

Comment: Don't use `ids` use a `class`, attach the click onto all then use either a `data-*` attribute or find the value by traversing to the first child tr > input

Comment: you should not keep the `id` same for every tag.you may use class for that

Comment: also whats div and main doing in your table tr's? that's invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE :-** Don't use same id for elements

You can get values by passing this with onclick function like `onclick="hanisdata(this)"`

**Example**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" 
    name="hanis" id="hanis" onclick="hanisdata(this)" value="<?php echo 
    $row['email']?>" ><?php echo $row['email']?></button>
```

Then you can get specific element in js and then can find parent and search for input field in that like below example.

**JS CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function hanisdata(el) {
    var hanis=$(el).parent().find("input").val();

    alert(hanis); 
    // AJAX code to send data to php file.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "hanis.php",
        data: {hanis:hanis},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
         $("#message").html(data);
        $("p").addClass("alert alert-success");
        },
        error: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
  });

 }

</script>
```